# Sign Up/Register Button not working (PHP AND AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax

The register button doesn't work. Once I complete the registraiton it just sits there and nothing happens.

I pressed the F12 button to see the errors and it showed this:(Internal Server Error)http://localhost/users/ajax_join Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

My register php page:

```
<?php require_once ('header.php'); ?>

<div class="span4 offset3">

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Join Now. It's Free!</h1>

    <form method="post" action="/users/ajax_join" id="signup-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <label>
            Username:
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="required"/>

        <br/>

        <label>
            Email:
        </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" class="required" />

        <br/>

        <label>
            Password:
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="****" class="required" />

        <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="sb_signup" value="Join Now" class="btn btn-warning"/>

    </form>

    <div id="signup_output_div"></div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="span2"></div>

<?php require_once 'sidebar.php'; ?>

<?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
```

users.php:

```
    /*
     * Register Form/Page
     */
    public function join() {
        if($this->loggedIn) 
        {
            redirect('/users');
            exit;
        }


    $this->load->view('join-now');
}


/*
 * Register via AJAX
 */
public function ajax_join() {

    if($this->input->post('sb_signup')) {

        unset($_POST['sb_signup']);

        $insert = array();

        foreach($this->input->post() as $k=>$v) {
            if($this->input->post($k, TRUE) != "") {
                $insert[$k] = $this->input->post($k, TRUE);
            }else{
                print '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
                print 'All fields are mandatory';
                print '</div>';
                exit;
            }
        }

        $this->db->where(array("username" => $this->input->post('username', TRUE)));
        $this->db->or_where(array("email" => $this->input->post('email', TRUE)));
        $user = $this->db->get("users");

        if(count($user->result())) {
            print '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
            print 'Username/Email taken, please chose another one.';
            print '</div>';
            exit;
        }

        $insert['ip'] = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $insert['password'] = md5($insert['password']);

        if($this->db->insert("users", $insert)) {
            $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', $this->db->insert_id());
            print '<div class="alert alert-success">';
            print 'You are now logged in. <a href="/users">My Account</a>';
            print '</div>';
        }else{
            print '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
            print 'DB Error';
            print '</div>';
        }


    }else{
        print '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
        print '-No post-';
        print '</div>';
    }


}
```

Help me

Comment: It's not solution but "require_once" and "require" are language constructs and not functions. Therefore they should be written without "()" brackets.

Comment: Show code which do you have under users/ajax_join url

Comment: I edited the post with the register code there, also when i click on 'http://localhost/users/ajax_join' it shows this: -No post-

Comment: "No Post" - is this code within a framework of some variety?

Comment: No, it's just that message, I think it comes from this:  }else{
        print '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
        print '-No post-';
        print '</div>';

Comment: Are you using any framework? What is `$this->input->post()` ?

Comment: @quentino `require` and `require_once` can be used with brackets as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with framework and I don't think the code has any frameworks. I can add user manually though the database but not with the register page

Comment: This looks like CI syntax.

Comment: *"Internal Server Error"* - check for errors then (and/or logs). It seems you're using the CodeIgniter framework, so use https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html if that's what you're using as a framework. If you don't know about your code and why you copied it in your PC in the first place, then it makes it all that much more harder to help. If not CI, then use PHP's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - could even be wrong paths; hard to say, could be anything.

Comment: @AndreyTserkus Yes, can be but shouldn't. @AnaVilar `$this->input->post()`is functionality in your code. In this case `input` is field in class which is used to store all input params from GET and POST, but we don't know how they have been saved there. Best way is check in error.log but if you don't know how do that, then you can try print data. Try ` $foo = $this->input->post(); print_r($foo); die;` after `if($this->input->post('sb_signup')) {`

Comment: I went to the php manager and looked for error logs but it only showed this: [12-Aug-2016 19:33:02 Europe/Minsk] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\controllers\users.php on line 239. I also try what you reccomended quentino but it gave me 500 internal server error

Comment: @AnaVilar What do you have in application\controllers\users.php on line 239? You can show few lines behind and few lines ahead or put whole  users.php if you can.

Comment: There's nothing there. Look: http://prntscr.com/c4xg31

Comment: @AnaVilar This is not a user.php. You must look at users.php on line 239

Comment: I know, I told you that there is only a blank space there. See: http://prntscr.com/c4xih4

Comment: @AnaVilar What do you have on beginning of `public function ajax_join() {` because unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) is means you use PUBLIC keyword in wrong context, maybe some bracket is in wrong place, hard to say without code.

Comment: I think I got this error when I accidentally deleted something in the code but I already undone that. I think it has something do with the ajax, just don't know what