# Ajax Form not inserting data in the database

Tags: database

When I click 'submit' in the form it just sits there endlessly without adding the data into the database.

It has something to do with localhost/ajax_join ERROR 500

Help!

Comment: please share your cods what you have tired yet???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922397/sign-up-register-button-not-working-php-and-ajax